# jasmine spyOn angularjs internal methods such as $filter('date')

Tags: angularjs, filter, jasmine

Please see the code in

http://jsfiddle.net/2Ny8x/69/

I wonder how I can add another spy to spyOn the method returned by $filter('date') so that I can verify

```
expect(something, something).toHaveBeenCalledWith('1234', 'dd-MMM-yyyy');
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to mock the filter passed into the controller, and return a spy from this mock. You can then test that the spy was called as normal.

Example:

```
describe('MyCtrl', function () {
  var filter, innerFilterSpy, http, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $http) {
    http = $http;
    innerFilterSpy = jasmine.createSpy();
    filter = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(innerFilterSpy);
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
      '$scope': scope,
      '$http': http,
      '$filter': filter
    });
  }));

  it('call $filter("date") and test()', function () {
      expect(scope.date).toBe('01-Jan-1970');
      expect(http.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(filter).toHaveBeenCalledWith('date');
      expect(innerFilterSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('1234', 'dd-MMM-yyyy');
  });
});
```

Comment: This helped but I wanted to point out it's misleading to inject $filter since you aren't using it.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed that now.